# Is it possible to get the SHA256 of an APK solely through ADB?

Tags: adb, apk, malware

I am currently working on a project which will identify malware that are residing on a device.

My aim is to make a hash-based detection of Android malware on a device by only accessing the ADB port of the device and getting the SHA-256 (MD5, SHA1, etc could also work) of the `base.apk` which resides in the app's data directory.

Is there any way to get the hash of an `.apk` file that is installed on a device using ADB, but without installing another app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most devices the command-line application `sha256sum` is present which can be used to generate the SHA-256 digest of one or more files.

It can be used via adb so that you can use it to generate a digest of each APK file without having to transfer it to the PC.